# What is wrong with Mysql trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

What is wrong with Mysql trigger?

```
CREATE TRIGGER ebdaa.active_cus AFTER UPDATE ON  ebdaa.appoints
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.confirmed = 1 OR NEW.attend =1 THEN 
            update  ebdaa.appoints SET NEW.active= 1 ;
        END IF;
    END;
```

Comment: You really need to ask the question more clearly. Did this result in an error? If so, what was the error? Or did it just do something different than you thought it would do? If so, what did you expect it to do, and what happened instead? That said, I think it's 90% likely that the problem is that you didn't use DELIMITER when defining the trigger, because that's a point of confusion for most people using triggers.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what's wrong with the trigger:

1) The SQL `UPDATE` statement in the body of the trigger s invalid. **`NEW.active`** is a reference to a value of the `active` column in the row that was just updated. That's a value from the row, not the name of a column.

2) Even if the SQL statement were modified to correct that issue, we don't really want to issue a subsequent UPDATE statement against the same row. (In some databases, this isn't allowed; I'm surprised that MySQL would allow it.)

3) This is an **`AFTER UPDATE`** trigger.  What we perceive as the intended result of this trigger (i.e. setting a column in the row to a particular value, when certain condition is true) would be much more efficiently achieved in a **`BEFORE UPDATE`** trigger.

Here's an example of a trigger that sets the `active` column to 1, when either `confirmed` or `attend` column is set to 1:

```
USE ebdaa;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER active_cus_bu
BEFORE UPDATE ON appoints
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF ( NEW.confirmed = 1 OR NEW.attend = 1 ) THEN
      SET NEW.active = 1;
   END IF; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: MySQL allows it and each update statement that triggers the UPDATE statement within the IF statement will fail. MySQL won't create this one as AFTER UPDATE trigger by the way. +1

Comment: @VMai: I concur (I think). If MySQL allows an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger to issue an `UPDATE` on the same table, of the same row, then that UPDATE statement would in turn fire the trigger, which would then perform another UPDATE, which would fire the trigger, ad infinitum. (MySQL has to throw an error somewhere to prevent that.) And yes,  setting `NEW.col` to a value would need to be performed in a **BEFORE UPDATE** trigger, rather than an AFTER UPDATE. (I may not have made that clear in my answer.)

Comment: For me your answer was and is clear and handled the main two issues (including the DELIMITER with resetting too): using a BEFORE UPDATE trigger and using a simple SET instead of an UPDATE that could lead indeed to an error message (instead of an endless loop). This would be true for an UPDATE on the same table in an BEFORE UPDATE trigger too.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the delimiter, set the trigger to  `before` and remove your update statement

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER ebdaa.active_cus BEFORE UPDATE ON ebdaa.appoints
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.confirmed = 1 OR NEW.attend = 1 THEN 
        SET NEW.active = 1;
    END IF;
END
|
delimiter ;
```